How can I create the ReflectedWorkItemId field in Shared Steps?
I was trying to migrate Test Cases and Shared Steps from TFS to Azure, but it is not possible to create the ReflectedWorkItemId field.
I'm using Azure Devops Migration Tools to migrate Test Cases and Shared Steps from TFS to Azure, but I can't create the ReflectedWorkItemId field in Azure, and to run Azure Devops Migration Tools this field is needed. Could anyone help me?
[15:00:14 INF] [16.0.2] Validating::Check all Target Work Items have the RefectedWorkItemId field
[15:00:14 WRN] [16.0.2] ValidatingRequiredField: Shared Steps does not contain Custom.ReflectedWorkItemId
[15:00:14 ERR] [16.0.2] Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.InvalidFieldValueException: Not all work items in scope contain a valid ReflectedWorkItemId Field!


In order to store the state for the migration you need to use a custom field, the ReflectedWorkItemId field which needs added to the Target only. Please refer to the similar ticket for the details:
Edit:
However, currently it's not supported to add ReflectedWorkItemId to Shared Steps. Please check the details in link howtomigrating-plans-and-suits.

It is only possible to create this field for other types of Work Item, for Shared Step it is not possible even if you have project owner permission

Thanks @FlavianeMarques, you are right!  its not posible to add ReflectedWorkItemId to Shared Steps. I will edit the reply with the info.
